# SFDX: how can I use a GitHub action script to deploy ONLY what was changed instead of ALL the metadata?

Tags: salesforcedx, github

I've set up GitHub actions in my Salesforce repository on GitHub. They're working fine, except they deploy *all* the metadata on the repository instead of only what was changed. I'm guessing I can leverage the **-d ./toDeploy** parameter and a *toDeploy* directory, but I'm unsure as to how.

I'm stumped as to what exactly the **-d ./toDeploy** means within the following SFDX command:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -l RunLocalTests -c -d ./toDeploy -u kevin@blah.com.sfhc -w 10
```

Currently the GitHub actions I've set up attempt to deploy *all* of the metadata on the master branch when a commit is made to the branch (instead of just deploying the delta). This is what the part of my GitHub action script that converts, validates, and deploys (but it is deploying *everything* in the repository):

```
# Convert to Deploy Source
- name: Convert to Deploy Source
  run: sfdx force:source:convert -r ./force-app -d ./toDeploy

# Run Validation of Deploy Source
- name: Run Validation on Deploy Source
  run: sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -l RunLocalTests -c -d ./toDeploy -u kevin@blah.com.sfhc -w 10

# Deploy
- name : Deploy to SF Org
  run: sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -l RunLocalTests -d ./toDeploy -u kevin@blah.com.sfhc -w 10
```

I don't have a toDeploy directory in my [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) project. I'm guessing that if I create one, then somehow I can use it to only deploy what was changed and not *all* the metadata. But I'm not sure how...

Comment: An MDAPI deploy deploys everything in the directory. `toDeploy` simply means a directory that contains the all the metadata to be deployed. If you just try to diff the file list and copy everything, you'd also have to make sure you get the appropriate XML files. This can be done, but is particularly difficult to do. You'd instead want to an Unlocked Package if you want to minimize deploy times.

Comment: @sfdcfox Can you elaborate on 'Unlocked Package'? I've read some on it but having difficulty integrating the concept into my use case. Can I just create a toDeploy directory at the root of my project? And does that directory expect a package.xml of the components, or just the component files themselves? Sorry for all the questions. I'm new to delta deployments using sfdx

Comment: An unlocked package runs as an install/upgrade, you build the package, and on upgrade it automatically performs a delta change on the server. This avoids all the complications of using delta deployments client-side, and also gives you the ability to install different versions as you wish in different orgs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use either `sfdx-git-delta` https://github.com/scolladon/sfdx-git-delta

Tool to create a dynamic package before running deployment or validation.
You can even create one yourself by using `git diff` command, but this will be a full remake of what the above plugin already does.

The steps are clearly mentioned in their readme file. And its open-source.

So your `yml` file should look like:

```
jobs:
  deployQA:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Install Salesforce CLI
        run: |
          npm install sfdx-cli -g
          pip install xq
          pip install yq
      - name: Install sfdxGit delta
        run: |
          echo y | sfdx plugins:install sfdx-git-delta
          sfdx sgd:source:delta --to "HEAD" --from "HEAD^"  --ignore ignorefile --output "."
          cat package/package.xml
      - uses: sfdx-actions/setup-sfdx@v1
        with:
          sfdx-auth-url: ${{ secrets.AUTH_SECRET_QA }}
      - name: 'Running checks'
        run: |
          sfdx force:source:deploy -x  package/package.xml --checkonly  -l 'RunLocalTests'  -u $SF_DEPLOYMENT_QA -w 60 > $deploymentResult
```

Remove `--checkOnly` if its a deployment. And use mdapi in your case.

Note : I am not sponsoring the plugin, but i have used it and it seems to be helping the use case.

Comment: This seems like a good option. Now if I can implement it correctly... I have the sfdx-git-delta installing in my pipeline fine, but when it does the diff and builds the package.xml file, it is only appending my pipeline.yml file to it, not the actual metadata changes. I added the pipeline.yml to my ignore, and then it just doesn't append anything to the package.xml, even though I've clearly made changes on some apex classes. Any thoughts there?

Comment: Without seeing the yml file and understanding your commit stratergy, i wont be able help you. Also if you have proper git setup and you use a feature branch to commit to your main branch, this plugin works like charm.